# Komma bei Sätzen mit "zu", die ein "und" verbindet

Tags: punctuation

Ich habe mehrere Seiten zu Sätzen mit "zu" durchsucht, war aber nicht in der Lage meine Frage aufzuklären. Nehmen wir etwa folgenden Satz:

> Zu seinen wichtigsten Verdiensten gehört ohne Zweifel, die materielle Zerstörung während des großen Sprunges aufgezeigt, und die damaligen Lebensbedingungen detailliert geschildert zu haben.

Ich glaube, das Komma nach "aufgezeigt" ist richtig, kann das aber nicht klären. Welche Regeln greifen hier?

Comment: Die Kommata in der eingerückten Passage gehören dort leider nicht hin.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Das Komma nach *aufgezeigt* ist nicht richtig. Wenn wir den Satz vereinfachen, handelt es sich um eine einfache Aufzählung mit *und*: *aufgezeigt und geschildert (zu haben)* – alles weitere in dem Satz ist für die Fragestellung nicht relevant. Ein ähnlicher Satz, bei dem das klarer wird:

- Sein Verdienst war es, die Situation beobachtet und detailliert beschrieben zu haben.

Das erste Komma, das der Infinitivgruppe *zu haben* geschuldet ist, ist interessanter, da sie theoretisch fakultativ, aber aufgrund der Komplexität des Satzes hier eindeutig angebracht ist, siehe [Regel 116](http://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/komma#K116), zitiert nach Duden:

> Infinitivgruppen kann man durch Komma[s] abtrennen, um die Gliederung
>   des Satzes deutlich zu machen oder um Missverständnisse
>   auszuschließen

Comment: Es sind zwei Infinitivkonstruktionen, die mit einem 'und' *gleichgestellt* sind: *aufgezeigt (zu haben)* und *geschildert zu haben*.

Comment: Das erste Komma ist, soweit ich das verstehe, sogar obligatorisch: Die Infinitivgruppe bezieht sich ja auf das "es", was den Beistrich immer notwendig macht, siehe Regel 117 Ziffer 3 (Beispiel 3) in deinem Link.

Comment: @sgf, guter Einwand, danke. Trifft auf meinen Beispielsatz (der auf das zweite Komma gemünzt war) auf jeden Fall zu. Im Originalsatz fehlt allerdings das Korrelatpronomen "es" – genau jenes "hinweisende Wort", an dem die Regel 117.3 festgemacht ist. Ob die Regel dann trotzdem gilt? Wahrscheinlich schon, denn schon bei einfachsten Sätzen wird ansonsten das Verständnis erschwert: *Unser Ziel war(,) zu gewinnen.* *Unser Verdienst war(,) gewonnen zu haben.* (Ich würde das *es* in diesen einfachen Sätzen ohnehin nicht weglassen.)